# Xcode "po" command

Tags: objective-c, nslog, po

When debugging, I need to check the value of a private [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) member, named str for example. After:

```
    self.str = xxxxxxx;
```

I typed "po self.str" in the console but only got "(NSString *) $37 = 0x00000000 "
So I tried:

```
    NSLog("%@", self.str);
```

…then I saw the string value.

### Why can’t I check the value of var using the command "po"?

Now I know it is because that I was using [lldb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLDB_%28debugger%29) as the debugger, as opposed to [gdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger). So the "po" ([print-object](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta45906)) command can only display the address of pointer. Is there any solution about print an object's description while using lldb?

**update:** I find `self` itself is not available. I guess the problem has connection with the class instance, which is a static variable. Is that the reason `po` cannot find the  pointer of `self`?

Comment: Your self.str is null: 0x00000000.

Comment: FYI, here's a mapping of gdb-to-lldb commands, showing syntax: http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: The property was probably released by the time you were trying to print it, debug it and check if it still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like a method without the dot notation

```
po [self str]
```

alternatively if you know the backing vars name you can just print it directly

```
po _str
```

Comment: I saw the answer like what you said before and tried that.  But both "po [self str]" and "po self.str" result in the same output"(NSString *) $37 = 0x00000000 <nil>".

Comment: Are you letting the debugger actually go past the line where the assignment is made or are you stopping on the assignment?